# CMake configure project

Tags: c++, cmake

I've got a question on cmake project configuration.

The following is my project structure.

```
trunk
     |
     |---- mylib
     |       |
     |        ---- mylib.h
     |        ---- mylib.c   
     |        ---- *MYLIB_CMakeList.txt*
     |
     |---- alib
     |       |
     |        ---- alib.h
     |        ---- alibName.lib
     |        ---- *ALIB_CMakeList.txt*
     |
     |
     |---- main
     |      |
     |       ---- main.cpp
     |       ---- *MAIN_CMakeList.txt*
     |       
      ---- *TOP_CMakeList.txt*
```

**mylib** subfolder contains the source code (c) to create my own static library. This code depends on **alib**.

The **main** subfolder contains the example code (C++) which uses **mylib**.

Here is how I've written my CMakeList files:

```
**TOP_CMakeList.txt**
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4)

add_subdirectory(mylib)
add_subdirectory(alib)
add_subdirectory(main)

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

**MYLIB_CMakeList.txt**
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4)
project(MyLib C)

if (WIN32)
    set(CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_PREFIX "")
endif ()

include_directories(${alib_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC mylib.c)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} alib)

set(${PROJECT_NAME}_DEFINITIONS CACHE INTERNAL "${PROJECT_NAME}: Definitions" FORCE)
set(${PROJECT_NAME}_INCLUDE_DIRS ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR} CACHE INTERNAL "${PROJECT_NAME}: Include Directories" FORCE)

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

**ALIB_CMakeList.txt**
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4)
project(ALib)


set(${PROJECT_NAME}_DEFINITIONS CACHE INTERNAL "${PROJECT_NAME}: Definitions" FORCE)
set(${PROJECT_NAME}_INCLUDE_DIRS ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR} CACHE INTERNAL "${PROJECT_NAME}: Include Directories" FORCE)

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


**MAIN_CMakeList**

make_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4)

project(Executable CPP)

file(GLOB CPP_FILES *.cpp)

add_definitions(${MyLib_DEFINITIONS})

include_directories(${MyLib_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${CPP_FILES})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} MyLib)
```

With such configuration it doesn't recognize the **alib** dependency of **mylib**. In particular (I'm developing under Windows) I get this error:

> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld:
>   cannot find -lalibName.lib

I can't figure out how to correctly do it. Any suggestions?

Comment: "[I]t doesn't work" is unfortunately not a very good problem description. Can you please elaborate on *how* it doesn't work? Does it build in the wrong order? Errors running CMake? Something else completely?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the `alib` project does not specify any kind of library targets the same way as mylib does:

Try adding this to alibs' CMake file

```
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC <<< alib SOURCES HERE >>>)
```

Comment: Thanks fritzone, but the alib project is composed of just a .lib file and .h file. I do not have the source code

Comment: @cq5beginner in this case you don't need a CMake file for it. Just use `link_directories` (https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/link_directories.html) and `target_link_libraries` (https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_link_libraries.html) for your mylib and specify the directory where the .lib file is

Comment: I tried but I get this error `No rule to make target .... needed by...` during the building

Answer (score 0):

Static libraries can't have dependencies(well, they can but they don't drag them with themselves) so there is no point in providing `alib` in `target_link_libraries(...)` for another static library. You should provide `alib` to the `add_execuable` command directly.

Alternatively, you can build a big static library from both `mylib` and `alib` but it will be less elegant and platfrom dependant. For gcc you should look at [ar](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/ar.html) tool.

---

Remove the `add_subdirectory(alib)` command, then remove CMake file from the alib subfolder — you don't need it. Then in the cmake file where you have your `add_executable` command put the following(after the line);

```
link_directories(../alib)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} alibName.lib)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I still get the `No rule to make target aLibName.lib, needed by main/Main.exe`